# Android sqlite data retriever

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    String table = SQLContract.tables.Score.TABLE_NAME;
    String [] columns = {SQLContract.tables.Score._ID,SQLContract.tables.Score.COLUMN_NAME_player_Name,SQLContract.tables.Score.COLUMN_NAME_Score};
    String selection = null;
    String [] selectionArgs = null;
    String groupBy = null;
    String having = null;
    String orderBy = null;
    Cursor c = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
    int [] to = {android.R.id.text1};

    String [] from = { SQLContract.tables.Score.COLUMN_NAME_player_Name};
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setListAdapter(sca);
```

I want to display data on list view bt this code is not workin......Some one help about this....???

This is error (1) no such column: _id

Comment: Rename yo primary key ColumnName to  **"_id"**

you are not extending the BaseAdapter so yu have to stick with their already defined column name "_id"

Comment: i am using SimpleCursorAdapter and _id is base column .....

Comment: Ok then look at my answer you have to assign this **_id** column to `int [] to = {android.R.id.text1};`

like the way you are doing for **FROM**

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] to = {android.R.id.text1};
```

Assign it the value of your Primary key Column for say `"_id"`

The Way You are assiging to

```
String [] from = { SQLContract.tables.Score.COLUMN_NAME_player_Name};
```

in `from` you show the Value that you want to display in List.

in `To` you bind the Value that you want to reutrn when list item is clicked.

MoreOver
Rename your `primary key ColumnName to "_id"` you are not extending the `BaseAdapter` so you have to stick with their `already defined column name "_id"`

Comment: this is a list activity




setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);

HighScore extends ListActivity